# Boundedness of a set of polygons

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

My question is related to my attempt to solve a problem in Powell's text on approximation theory.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of polygons in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with strictly positive area.

Define the distance between any two such polygons, say $A$ and $B$, to be $d(A,B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $A \Delta B = (A - B) \cup(B-A)$ is the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.

Let $P_0 \in \mathcal{P}$ and $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary.

Consider the open ball : $B = \{ P \in \mathcal{P} : d(P,P_0) < \delta \}$.

Does there exist an $R > 0$ such that each $P \in B$ is contained in the following ball of $\mathbb{R}^2:$ $\{ x : \| x \| \leq R \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following sequence of polygons $Q_1, Q_2,\dots$ in $P$:

The first polygon $Q_1$ is $P_0$, with a triangle $T_1$ of area $\frac{\delta}{2}$ attached to the side of it.
The second polygon $Q_2$ is similar, except now you attach a triangle $T_2$ to the side that has twice the height of $T_1$, but half of its base width.
Keep repeating this construction to get $Q_{i+1}$ from $Q_i$ --- obtaining a sequence of polygons that look like $P_0$ with ever longer, thinner triangles of area $\frac{\delta}{2}$ attached.

The sequence of heights of the attached triangles is unbounded, so for all $R$, you can find a polygon $Q_i$ that does **not** fit inside the ball of radius $R$.